# ReferenceError: my var is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing an application for testing NodeJS .
A login and registration system .
So I test if the user data for the registration are not already in the database .

But it does not work on the email.
I have this error:

```
    ReferenceError: mailDispo is not defined
   at /var/www/app.js:72:12
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at next (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at /var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
   at Function.proto.process_params (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
   at next (/var/www/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
   at /var/www/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:107:5
   at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/www/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:136:7)
```

But if I reload the page, although it appears to me the error as what the email is already in use !
An idea ?

Opps i forgot the code :

```
  var express = require('express');
var body = require('body-parser');
var render = require('ejs');
var app = express();

var mysql = require('mysql');

var mySqlClient = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "******",
    password: "*******!",
    database: "******"
});
app.use(body.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(body.urlencoded({// to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));


app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    var selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM user';

    var sqlQuery = mySqlClient.query(selectQuery);

    sqlQuery.on("result", function (row) {
        console.log('pseudo: ' + row.pseudo);
        console.log('mail: ' + row.mail);
    });

    sqlQuery.on("end", function () {
        mySqlClient.end();
    });

    sqlQuery.on("error", function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    response.sendfile('html/index.html');
});


app.get('/signup', function (request, response) {
    response.render('signup.ejs', {
        titre: 'Inscription sur War.io'
    });
});
//Inscription
app.post('/signup', function (request, response) {
    var pseudo = request.body.pseudo;
    var mail = request.body.mail;
    var password = request.body.password;
    var checkMail = "select id from user where mail=" + mysql.escape(mail);
    sqlQueryMail = mySqlClient.query(checkMail);
    sqlQueryMail.on("result", function (row) {
        if (row.id) {
            mailDispo = 0;
            errorMail = "Adresse email deja use";
        } else {
           mailDispo = 1;
        }
     });

        var checkUser = "select id from user where pseudo=" + mysql.escape(pseudo);
        sqlQueryUser = mySqlClient.query(checkUser);
        sqlQueryUser.on("result", function (row) {
            if (row.id) {
               pseudoDispo = 0;
               errorPseudo = "Pseudo deja use";            
            } else {
               pseudoDispo = 1;
            }
        });
        if(mailDispo == 1 &&  pseudoDispo == 1){
            mySqlClient.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', {
                pseudo: pseudo,
                mail: mail,
                pass: password
            }, function (err, result) {
                if (err){
                   throw err;
                } else {

                console.log(result.insertId);

               }
            });
       } else {
       reponse.render('signup.ejs', {
           'titre': 'War.io signup',
           'errorPseudo': errorPseudo,
           'errorMail': errorMail
      });

     }
    });
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: You'll have to post the code involved or else nobody will be able to help.

Comment: Is... `mailDispo` defined where you use it?

Comment: `mailDispo` isn't defined. Add `var mailDispo;` somehere in the route function, e.g. on the line after `var checkMail = ...`.

Comment: here => L72 : if(mailDispo == 1 &&  pseudoDispo == 1) I have this error.. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to define the variable at the top level of the function. This sets it as a scope variable inside of the function instead of it being a property on the global object, which is what defining it in that if loop (without var) will do.

```
app.post('/signup', function (request, response) {
    var mailDispo;
    var pseudo = request.body.pseudo;
    var mail = request.body.mail;
    var password = request.body.password;
    var checkMail = "select id from user where mail=" +       mysql.escape(mail);
    sqlQueryMail = mySqlClient.query(checkMail);
    sqlQueryMail.on("result", function (row) {
    if (row.id) {
        mailDispo = 0;
        errorMail = "Adresse email deja use";
    } else {
       mailDispo = 1;
    }
 });
```